# Using underscore templates in a chrome app

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am building a chrome app and getting an unsafe eval error.
I know that eval is now allowed on chrome extensions but when I am adding to the manifest

```
  "content_security_policy": "default-src  'unsafe-eval'; script-src   'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'"
```

I get an error in the extension tab

```
'content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.
```

Is there a way to allow unsafe eval in a chrome app

Comment: That doesn't appear to be correct syntax; did you copy and paste correctly?  What does this have to do with underscore?  Please convince us that unsafe eval is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Strict CSP cannot be overridden in a Chrome App. [Read the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy).